# Node.js, Forever.js, is it possible to see additional information using "forever list"

Tags: node.js, forever

We use [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/) and have a number of Node.js apps running. When we do "forever list" we see:

```
info:   Forever processes running
data:   uid  command       script        forever pid   logfile        uptime
data:   [0]  /usr/bin/node app.js    27944   5656  /home/....log  1:16:27:52.625
...
```

We have a number of apps all called "app.js" so it is really unclear which app is what. Is there a way to configure forever so it can include the script path or something? Do we have to rename all our "app.js" files to something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution #1:**

From https://github.com/andrewmartin/forever#using-forever-from-the-command-line

```
--uid            Process uid, useful as a namespace for processes 
                 (must wrap in a string)
                 eg. forever start --uid "production" app.js
                     forever stop production
```

**Solution #2:**

You can start your app using full path: `forever start /var/www/project_name/app.js`

```
info:   Forever processes running
data:   uid  command       script                          forever pid   logfile        uptime
data:   [0]  /usr/bin/node /var/www/project_name/app.js    27944   5656  /home/....log  1:16:27:52.625
...
```

**Solution #3:**

You also can add an unused command line param like: `forever start app.js project_name`

```
info:   Forever processes running
data:   uid  command       script                 forever pid   logfile        uptime
data:   [0]  /usr/bin/node app.js project_name    27944   5656  /home/....log  1:16:27:52.625
...
```